# Session Variables

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, gxt, gwt2, gwt-ext

How can i add Session Variable visible to the whole application in GWT?

like in C# you would do something like

```
Session.Add("mySessionVal", "Hello");
```

How do you do this in GWT?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT is client side, web sessions are server-side.

GWT applications are not typical page-by-page web application. You always stay on the same page (check URL bar in browser).

So, you can simply set a global (public static) field in some class and it will be visible by all other objects in GWT app.

Comment: GWT is not 100% frontend. There is a backend portion as well.

Answer (score 1):

This might suffice the purpose of accessing variables in the entire GWT application:

[Developer's Guide - Client-side Storage (Web Storage)](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage)